# Does exist an OpenACC counterpart of the OpenMP directive THREADPRIVATE?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, openacc

In my OpenMP project, I use a do loop over a threaded subroutine "tool" and am restricted to pass a single-variate function to the threaded subroutine "tool." However, in my mathematical model, the function has to take one more argument, so I need to feed the second thread-dependent variables to respective threads.

For the function I need, I simply add the directive "!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(i)," And it works perfect. I am wondering how to port this code to OpenACC.

It seems to me that the new OpenACC 2.0 standard can handle this problem, but I could not find any detailed tutorial with sample code over the Internet to illustrate the use of the new directive such as "routine" to invoke thread-dependent functions or subroutines within the parallel zone.

Thanks.

Lee

1. MAIN.F90

   ```
   program main 
   use toolbox 
   real :: a(5),c(5) 
   integer :: j 

   a = [((j),j=1,9,2)] 
   b = [((j),j=2,10,2)] 

   !$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(b) 
   do j=1,5 
     i=j 
     call tool(fun1,a(j),c(j)) 
   enddo 
   !$OMP END PARALLEL DO 
   write(6,'5(f3,x)') c 
   end program main
   ```
2. MODEL.F90

   ```
   module toolbox
   integer :: i 
   !$OMP THREADPRIVATE(i) 
   real :: b(5) 
   contains 
   subroutine tool(func,e,f) 
     interface 
     real function func(x) 
       real :: x 
     end function func 
     end interface 
     real :: e,f 
     f=func(e) 
   end subroutine tool 
   function fun1(z) 
     real :: fun1,z 
     fun1=z+b(i) 
   end function fun1 
   end module toolbox
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OpenACC does not have an equivalent to threadprivate.

If you are not restricted to the type for your function argument, you should make a derived type and send that.